# Ruby on Rails Gemfile Development and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm working on porting a JS library to rails. This will be my first gem that I'm attempting to create and I seem to have run into a bit of a snag.

The issue that I have is that there will necessarily be some JavaScript elements to the gem. However, I seem to be unable to find out how to do this.

Example:

/lib/rotrails.rb

```
module RotRails
    def self.isSupported
        #Call JS function "isSupported() in /vendor/assets/javascript/rotrails.js
    end
end
```

/vendor/assets/javascript/rotrails.js

```
Function isSupported() {
     return !!(document.createElement("canvas").getContext && Function.prototype.bind);
}
```

Any assistance on how to solve this problem as well as pass the result back to the Rails Gem would be appreciated.

Update: To clarify, the rails part is logic calculations and the JavaScript is the frontend for the program. I am looking for the most logical way to have the two communicate or a reference to how to work with JavaScript when creating gemfiles.

Thanks!

Comment: You know that JavaScript runs on the client, and the Ruby runs on the server, right?

Comment: I do, yes, there must be a way to have the two talk with each other.

Comment: Ajax? http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP

Comment: @Amit Not that way, there isn't. You can't invoke arbitrary JS methods in your Ruby code. You shouldn't have to anyways; perform your feature detection on the client, and act accordingly. Your Rails server should almost never need to be concerned with what the browser supports.

Comment: Then let me rephrase the situation. There will be logic calculations happening on the backend (Rails), and drawing happening on the frontend (JavaScript). What would be the most correct way to communicate the needed data from one to the other and back again?

Comment: JS on the client and Rails on the server. You can use JQuery ajax calls from the client to the server. The server can't call the client at all, unless you use either 'long calls' or websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider to use (or simply try) https://rails-assets.org/ instead of porting your js library manually ?